# Guide to create a small business network?

Tags: networking

Any guide/book/tutorial related to the subject of designing a network?

It would also be helpful if it mentions using a cloud server.

Edit: We want to move our server to a online destination.

We are running backups, accounting software, AD and Fax on the server. We don't require AD on the online server, but it would be good to have it.

7 or 8 workstations. 1 Fax machine which is also a printer and 2 more printers. They are all connected.

This is the first time we are doing something like this, we have some experience with server but only on the physical location. I guess we have to create a VPN between the cloud server and the network. Is that kind of "books" I'm looking for. Books that can advice me on the best ways to substitute the server.

Comment: I'd suggest refining the question or posting another question with details. What business and what services does it need? How many workstations? Are you hosting anything? On site admin? What expertise do you or the admins have? etc. etc...otherwise this is hopelessly vague. You can go to Barnes and Noble and they usually have a shelf of books on home networking that would fit the description.

Answer (score 1):

With your environment, I see alot of negatives and no real positives in you moving to a cloud hosted server with your server requirements.

Fax: you need a phone line for your fax printer; this not going to work in a cloud hosted server; you could move to a Fax2Email gateway type service I guess, but you'll likely not be able to keep your same phone number.

Performance: it'll be slow, unless you've got a 10Mbps or greater synchronous, guaranteed/SLA pipe at your office, to do just about anything on the server save for accessing Web resources if you're planning on hosting a Web site/application on it.

Accounting/client-server software: Anything that's UDP and/or latency-sensitive likely will be brutally-slow or won't work at all.

Cost: an always-on server with decent redundant/permanent storage in the cloud is going to be ballbark around $100-$200 a month.

The only "cloud" option I could see being useful at your size of company would be a) online backups and b) going with something Google Apps for your email, shared documents, etc.  You'd still need a server (or a workstation acting as a server) to host your accounting software and your fax printer though if you choose to keep your existing phone line and fax printer.

Comment: Thank you. I have provided more information about the problem on the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any to recommend. However, if the business is planning on using "cloud" resources exclusively, then their network only needs to be "we have a shared internet connection." Nothing else to build.

Probably the best advice that I can give you is to hire a qualified local consultant. Ask around for recommendations from other small local businesses.

If you were planning on doing this yourself, then my advice is to become a qualified consultant. Getting to that stage may include working for one, however.

Comment: Thank you. We have some experience in networking but as far as cloud is related, none.